# Importing Shape Key Animation using Evaluation Time into Unity

Tags: animation, unity, shape-keys, data-blocks

I have been trying to get an animation imported into Unity that is using shape keys. Specifically I am using an Evaluation Time animation, so absolute shape keys. If I am using Relative animation I can follow this guys, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvjwTnS6vhA, steps and they work perfectly. If I follow the same steps but just uncheck that Relative box to go to Absolute Shape Keys I am unable to get the animation exported to unity. Things I am noticing are that the shape keys don't show up in the dope editor in absolute mode the way they do in relative. I am also not able to see or click the F key, similar to this guys issue, ["F" Button in Shape Key Editor Not Showing Up - Why Not?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64681/f-button-in-shape-key-editor-not-showing-up-why-not/64699), even after clicking the plus symbol. If I click the plus symbol to make new shape key data, I see the F key for a second, but right when I move my mouse, it disappears! Seems like a bug to me?

So, has anyone gotten absolute (evaluation time) shape key animations into Unity?